# How to fetch records up to particular data

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Table tb data as below

```
id  remarks   status   key
------------------------------------
1    dfe        1       340              
2    ert        4       340
3    aaa        6       340
4    gh         7       340
5    bnh        2       341
6    xdc        6       341
7    qqq        1       341
8    rty        3       343
9    mnh        1       343
10   ppo        3       343
11   oit        6       343
```

I want to get list of id upto status 6 by grouping key.

```
select id 
from tb 
where status in (6) AND key in (select key_list from temporary_table)
group by key;
```

I didnt get required records.

For example: I need output as below for

```
key 340
id
---
1
2
3

For key 341
id
---
5
6

For key 343
id
---
8
9
10
11
```

Note: Orginal key column data not in order, it is in suffle. For easy understanding in given list this.

Comment: What is the desired result if for a given key, the status is never 6? Also, when you say "for key ..." what do you mean? Is that an input variable (bind variable in the query), and you need the result set for one key at a time, or do you need the query to return rows for all keys in a single result set?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select tb.*  -- or whatever columns you want
from tb
where tb.id <= (select min(tb2.id)
                from tb tb2
                where tb2.key = tb.key and tb2.status = 6
               );
```

Alternatively, you can use a window function:

```
select tb.id
from (select tb.*,
             min(case when status = 6 then id end) over (partition by key) as id_6
      from tb
     ) tb
where id <= id_6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

1. You need a query to return the respective id's for all keys in a
   single query;
2. If for a given key the status is never 6, then you must return all
   the rows for that key

you can do this with `match_recognize`:

```
select key, id
from   tb
match_recognize(
  partition by key
  order     by id
  all rows  per match
  pattern   ( ^ a* b? )
  define    a as status != 6
);
```

If, instead, you must give the query a single input key as a variable, and return the result just for that key, you can modify the query like this:

```
select id
from   (select id, status from tb where key = :input_key)
match_recognize(
  order     by id
  all rows  per match
  pattern   ( ^ a* b? )
  define    a as status != 6
);
```